# while installation mediasoup it showing error

Tags: javascript, node.js, webrtc, mediasoup

Trying to install by Command prompt in window7 **64bit**

[image: npm i mediasoup]

after `npm cache --force clean`[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a c++ compiler on your machine. On windows, it's usually the vc++ compiler that comes with any installation of Visual Studio. Once you found that, make sure to add msbuild to your PATH variable (some forums said to make it a system variable, but i doubt).